# Show certain information in Listbox from TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I would like to be able to add elements to the Listbox object and have the elements be shown in a certain way. Let's say I add lowercase elements but want them to be shown in uppercase or add tuples to the Listbox and only want to show the first element of the tuple.

In OptionMenu it is possible to set the label attribute when adding an item through .add_command(), but Listbox does not have this option.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Example:
I want to only show cities in lowercase and have it carry more information for the onselect such as the entire tuple or original look of a string

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))

def onselect(event):
    w = event.widget
    if (w.curselection() == ()): return
    index = int(w.curselection()[0])
    value = w.get(index)
    print(value) # prints tuple on select

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: onselect(event))
listbox.pack()


listContent = ((1, 'LONDON', 'A city in Great Britain'), 
                (2, 'NEW YORK', 'A city in USA'), 
                (3, 'PARIS', 'A city in France'))

# refresh listbox with content
listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
for item in listContent:
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item) # Sadly shows entire tuple in listbox

root.mainloop()
```

Example with working OptionMenu:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
cvar = tk.StringVar(root)
cvar.set("-")
optionlist = ((1, 'LONDON', 'A city in Great Britain'), 
                (2, 'NEW YORK', "A city in USA"), 
                (3, "PARIS", "A city in France"))

def doNothing():
    return

def contentcallback(x, content):
    print(content)

def refresh(contentlist):
    optionmenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')

    for content in contentlist:
        optionmenu['menu'].add_command(label=content[1].lower(), command=tk._setit(cvar, content[1].lower(), lambda x,c=content:contentcallback(x, c)))

optionmenu = tk.OptionMenu(root, cvar, *optionlist, command=doNothing)
optionmenu.pack()

refresh(optionlist)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post your minimized code here and we have to help you..

Comment: You can do whatever you want before inserting to the listbox.  So what is the problem?

Comment: @Alchimie Hope this is sufficient :D

Comment: @acw1668 I want to use the Listbox to reflect objects but it carries no other information than names. I could use the names as keys to map to the objects but I would rather have the Listbox control it and allow duplicates.

Comment: `def onselect(content): print(content)`, `listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda _: onselect(listContent[listbox.curselection()[0]]))` and `listbox.insert(tk.END, item[1].lower())`.  Is it what you want?

Comment: @acw1668 That was what I was looking for thanks :D
Do you know if calling listbox.bind multiple times changes the bond or can cause problems? In case I change listContent

Comment: Why do you want to call `listbox.bind()` multiple times as it need to be called once? Changing `listContent` does not affect the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code become like This:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))

def onselect(event):
    value=listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    for lst in listContent:
        if value in lst:
            break
    print(lst)

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: onselect(event))
listbox.pack()


listContent = ((1, 'LONDON', 'A city in Great Britain'), 
                (2, 'NEW YORK', 'A city in USA'), 
                (3, 'PARIS', 'A city in France'))

# refresh listbox with content
listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
for item in listContent:
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item[1]) # Here Use item[1] for show Only the second element
root.mainloop()
```

You can change listContent from list of lists to dictionary for minimize your code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 400))

def onselect(event):
    value=listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    print(value + ' : ' +listContent[value])

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda event: onselect(event))
listbox.pack()

listContent = {'LONDON': 'A city in Great Britain', 
            'NEW YORK': 'A city in USA', 
            'PARIS': 'A city in France'}

listbox.delete(0,tk.END)
for item in listContent.keys():
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item) 
root.mainloop()
```